# Setting a php variable and displaying it on another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am wanting to run this script to update the db and then check if it did then in fact update and then set a variable saying so and redirect back the the previous page and echo out wither the successful update or unsuccessful update on that page.  Currently it runs perfectly but will not echo out the successful or unsuccessful part.  What can I do to fix this?

```
<?php
include_once('../../../_php/connect.php');

$update_e_id = $_POST['error_id'];

//Update unresolved to resolved
mysql_query("UPDATE error SET resolution='resolved' WHERE id=" . $update_e_id . " 
AND resolution='unresolved'");

//Check if it updated
$checkE_update = "SELECT * FROM error WHERE id=" . $update_e_id . " AND 
 resolution='resolved'";
$results = mysql_query($checkE_update);
$nr = mysql_num_rows($results);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $checkResolution = $row['resolution'];
}
if($checkResolution = 'resolved') {
    $successfullyUpdated = "<p>The error is now resolved.</p>";
    header("Location: ../lib_errors.php");
}   else {
        $didnotUpdateError = "<p>The update was unsuccessful.</p>";
        header("Location: ../lib_errors.php");
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql-injections. Also don't use mysql_, it's deprecated. Use mysqli or pdo instead.

Comment: Yeah, this is really insecure. Use prepared statements or at least unescape your passed variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use a session... make sure you have this at the top of every page in php tags;

```
session_start();
```

then do

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $varName;
```

then on another page you can echo out the session

```
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SESSION` way mentioned in the other answers is one approach. Another could be to store the message about success or unsuccess in a `$_GET` variable and pass them in the called URI:

```
// ...
if($checkResolution = 'resolved') {
    $status = 'success';
    $message = "<p>The error is now resolved.</p>";
} else {
    $status = 'error;
    $message = "<p>The update was unsuccessful.</p>";
}
$uri = '../lib_errors.php?status='.$status.'&message='.$message;
header('Location: '.$uri);
```

And then in your `lib_errors.php` you can use:

```
$status  = $_GET['status'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($checkResolution = 'resolved') {
    $successfullyUpdated = "<p>The error is now resolved.</p>";
    header("Location: ../lib_errors.php?msg=The error is now resolved.");
}   else {
        $didnotUpdateError = "<p>The update was unsuccessful.</p>";
        header("Location: ../lib_errors.php?msg=The update was unsuccessful.?msg=");
    }
 ?>
```

and echo this message on your redirection page as:

```
<?php echo $_GET['msg']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are again executing selection query. From update query itself you will get success or failed

```
//Update unresolved to resolved
$rs = mysql_query("UPDATE error SET resolution='resolved' WHERE id=".$update_e_id." AND resolution='unresolved'");
if($rs) {
    header("Location: ../lib_errors.php?msg=The error is now resolved");
}
else {
    header("Location: ../lib_errors.php?msg=The update was unsuccessful");
}
```

And in lib_error.php you will get your message as `$_GET['msg'];` you can echo it wherever you want